# Bluetooth to n - no of Device

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it Possible to connect one Bluetooth activated Phone to n number of Phones with Bluetooth.. some thing like a Bluetooth Broadcasting from a phone to any number of listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with the bluetooth, use the piconet. I believe it's possible in Android but I'm not sure!

Comment: just to understand Bluetooth piconets before i Google it up.. is it hardware or software ? and is it possible from existing phones ?

Comment: It's software part of Bluetooth, I think th recent phone can be use the piconet, I don't know if the piconet was introduice in the BT 2.1 or BT 3.0

Comment: Thanks buddy i will try to dig up more now :) if u do come across anything regarding android programming let me know :)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html should be all the code you need just create a new UUID for the next device

Answer (score 1):

yes you can connect to unto 7 devices - it is not possible to broadcast using android , but you can loop around and send messages to each of the device one at a time